# Inner class with main method doesn't compile

Tags: java

```
abstract class Manager {

    static void test() {
        System.out.println(12);
    }

    class Manager1 {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println(Manager.test());
        }
     }
}
```

It's producing a compile time error. Can an abstract class have a `static` method with `void` type?

Comment: Is `Manager1` extending `Manager` in this case? You shouldn't nest `Manager1` inside of `Manager`.

Comment: @gwin003, I don't think so

Answer (score 12):

Non-static inner classes cannot have `static` methods - only top-level and static classes can (as per [JLS §8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).

Furthermore:

```
System.out.println(Manager.test());
```

`Manager.test()` is void: you can't print that.